# Pass a pointer to derived class as parameter of Base class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base1
{
  public:

  virtual int virt1() { return 100; }

  int data1;
};

class Derived : public Base1
{
  public:

  virtual int virt1() { return 150; }

  int derivedData;
};

int Global1( Base1 * b1 )
{
  return b1->virt1();
}

main()
{
  Derived * d = new Derived;
  cout << Global1(d);
}
```

I have this code fragment, and my question is, when we pass the pointer d to the function Global1, what's the class of the pointer that we pass into the function, is that derived or base1? If it's a base1 class, why would it print 150.

Comment: The class `Derived` contains a `Base` class subobject via inheritance. When you pass `d` to `Global1`, `b1` will point to its base class suboject. Since `virt1()` is virtual in the base class, the derived class's `virt1()` function will be called because name binding will be deferred until runtime, where the dynamic type of `b1` will be `Derived`.

Comment: If you want to specifically call the base class function you can do it by specifying the scope, e.g. `return b1->Base1::virt1();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're showing here is the whole point of virtual functions.  When you declare a function in a base class as virtual, you are saying that the compiler should defer binding a function call until runtime.

Had you not declared virt1() as virtual, the compiler would have looked at the object you passed as an instance of Base1 and call virt1() on that class, returning 100.

With the virtual function, the compiler waits until runtime to see what the actual type is.  A  class with virtual methods has a pointer embedded in the object that points to a table of virtual functions to call.  At runtime your application pulls the correct version of vert1() and calls that, so in this case it will return 150.